# MySQL datetime column WHERE col IS NULL fails

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I cannot get my very basic SQL query to work as it returns 0 values despite the fact that there are clearly nulls

### query

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  leads AS l
  JOIN closes c ON l.id = c.lead_id
 WHERE
  c.close_date IS NULL
```

### DDL

```
CREATE TABLE closes
(
  id               INT AUTO_INCREMENT
    PRIMARY KEY,
  lead_id          INT          NOT NULL,
  close_date       DATETIME     NULL,
  close_type       VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  primary_agent    VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  price            FLOAT        NULL,
  gross_commission FLOAT        NULL,
  company_dollar   FLOAT        NULL,
  address          VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  city             VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  state            VARCHAR(10)  NULL,
  zip              VARCHAR(10)  NULL,
  CONSTRAINT closes_ibfk_1
  FOREIGN KEY (lead_id) REFERENCES leads (id)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX lead_id
  ON closes (lead_id);
```

I should mention that I am inserting the data with a python web scraper and SQLAlchemy. If the data is not scraped it will be `None` on insert.

Here is a screenshot of datagrip showing a null value in the row

[image]

### EDIT

Alright so I went ahead and ran the following on some of the entries in the table where the value was already `<null>`

```
UPDATE closes
  SET close_date = NULL
WHERE
  lead_id = <INTEGERVAL>
;
```

What is interesting now is that when running the original query I do actually return the 2 records that I ran the update query for (the expected outcome). This would lead me to believe that the issues is with how my SQLAlchemy model is mapping the values on insert.

### models.py

```
class Close(db.Model, ItemMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'closes'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    lead_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('leads.id'), nullable=False)
    close_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    close_type = db.Column(db.String(255))
    primary_agent = db.Column(db.String(255))
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    gross_commission = db.Column(db.Float)
    company_dollar = db.Column(db.Float)
    address = db.Column(db.String(255))
    city = db.Column(db.String(255))
    state = db.Column(db.String(10))
    zip = db.Column(db.String(10))

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.build_from_item(item)

    def build_from_item(self, item):
        for k, v in item.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

But I am fairly confident the value is a python `None` in the event no value is scraped from the website. My understanding is that SQLAlchemy would map a `None` to `NULL` on insert and given that `nullable=True` is the default setting, which can seen on the generated DDL, I am still at a loss as to why it appears to be `NULL` when in reality it is not behaving that way.

### EDIT 2

Only place where I think the issue would be happening is where my spider actually scrapes the data and assigns it to the `Item` which is shown below

## closes.py

```
# item['close_date'] = None at this point
try:
    item['close_date'] = arrow.get(item['close_date'], 'MMM D, YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
except ParserError as e:
    # Maybe item['close_date'] = None here?
    spider.logger.error(f'Parse error: {item["close_date"]} - {e}')
```

In the python code I've written this would appear to be the place where the issue would arise. But if `arrow.get` throws an exception the value of `item['close_date']` should still be `None`. If that is not the case and even if it is it does not explain why it appears that the record value is `NULL` even thought it does not behave like it is.

Comment: What sort of object is arrow?  Assuming dict.get() behavior, it's not returning a None value for this call 'arrow.get(item['close_date'], 'MMM D, YYYY')'

Comment: It's an `Arrow` object. I do realize at that point it is not returning none. it should be returning an Arrow object which is basically a date or it is throwing an exception as it cannot parse the date and thus `item['close_date']` should still be `None` http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're having an issue with the join, not the NULL value.  The query below returns 1 result for me.  More info about your data, the software used for querying (I tested with SQL Yog), and applicable versions might help.

**EDIT**

It could be that you're having issues with MySQL's 'zero date'.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html

> MySQL permits you to store a “zero” value of '0000-00-00' as a “dummy
>   date.” This is in some cases more convenient than using NULL values,
>   and uses less data and index space. To disallow '0000-00-00', enable
>   the NO_ZERO_DATE mode.

I've updated the SQL data below to include a zero date in the INSERT and SELECT's WHERE.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS closes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS leads;

CREATE TABLE leads (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT  INTO leads(id) VALUES (1),(2),(3);

CREATE TABLE closes (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  lead_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  close_date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  close_type VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  primary_agent VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  price FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  gross_commission FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  company_dollar FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  address VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  city VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  state VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  zip VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY lead_id (lead_id),
  CONSTRAINT closes_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (lead_id) REFERENCES leads (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT  INTO closes(id,lead_id,close_date,close_type,primary_agent,price,gross_commission,company_dollar,address,city,state,zip) 
VALUES 
(1,3,'0000-00-0000',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(2,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(3,2,'2018-01-09 17:01:44',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);

SELECT
  *
FROM
  leads AS l
  JOIN closes c ON l.id = c.lead_id
 WHERE
  c.close_date IS NULL OR c.close_date = '0000-00-00';
```

Comment: I'm not having any issue with the join clause as when I remove the `WHERE` clause it will return all leads that are also in the close table (i.e. all close records). The problem with your answer is that you actually inserted a non null value into the database for the `close_date` column which isn't consistent with the original question.

Comment: The insert is adding a NULL and non-NULL value, 2 inserts in one line.

Comment: @Adam Edited and updated to move to 1 insert per line and include a possible issue with zero dates.